# Adding 'App Available' functionality to websites

Tags: javascript, html, exe

Recently while visiting some websites I saw this pop up in the search bar

[image]

Upon clicking this an `.exe` file was downloaded. An example website of this is [one](https://www.redbull.com/int-en/redbullracing). A similar thing could be seen in Chrome and Edge although Firefox didn't show this.

How can I do the same with my website as well?

Comment: With a download link? `<a download href="file.exe">` ?

Comment: @JeremyThille That would be a link but I want to get a icon in the search bar that would allow me to get the app. I have added a link to the website where I saw this

Comment: What browser…? That's some browser-specific thing, probably some `<meta>` tag that you can add.

Comment: On my macOS Chrome, this manifests as a button with a popover: https://i.imgur.com/DTwGMTk.png

Comment: @deceze I found nothing at mdn about such a tag. I think I would have go to the 2 second page of search results :(

Answer (score 1):

I found this https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/06/pwa-install-addressbar that can be helpful for Chrome. It seems that you need to follow these criteria https://web.dev/customize-install/#criteria to promote your web app. I understood that Chrome shows an install button in your address bar automatically in these conditions.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a so called "[Progressive web application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_application)" (PWA). To make this icon appear, you have to meet some [criteria](https://web.dev/install-criteria/).

Answer (score 1):

According to [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps), this is called PWA.

> In order to call a Web App a PWA, technically speaking it should have the following features: Secure contexts (HTTPS), one or more Service Workers, and a manifest file.

[Here you can see the full details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps).

All you need is to have those 3 things done and the browser will show this prompt automatically.

[Here](https://web.dev/install-criteria/) is another descriptive details about what needs to be done in order to achieve this install effect.

Pay attention that different browsers have different requirements for doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are trying to mention in your question is called as **Progressive Web App (PWA)**

Here's what [web.dev](https://web.dev) says

> Progressive Web Apps (PWA) are built and enhanced with modern APIs to deliver enhanced capabilities, reliability, and installability while reaching anyone, anywhere, on any device with a single codebase.

In layman terms, PWA is just an app which is made from your website's codebase & provides you the same feel as if you are using an application downloaded from play store or app store.

Coming to how you can make your website to support PWA:

Basically 3 things are needed to convert your web app into a PWA, these are

- App should be served over HTTPS
- Manifest.json file
- Service Worker

[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps) have a nice introduction on this. I am quoting here few things from there.

Secure contexts (HTTPS)

> The web application must be served over a secure network. Being a secure site is not only a best practice, but it also establishes your web application as a trusted site especially if users need to make secure transactions. Most of the features related to a PWA such as geolocation and even service workers are available only once the app has been loaded using HTTPS.

Manifest file

> A JSON file that controls how your app appears to the user and ensures that progressive web apps are discoverable. It describes the name of the app, the start URL, icons, and all of the other details necessary to transform the website into an app-like format.

Service workers

> A service worker is a script that allows intercepting and control of how a web browser handles its network requests and asset caching. With service workers, web developers can create reliably fast web pages and offline experiences.

To help you out with step wise process of creating a PWA, I am adding a reference to a very good tutorial below, you can read it out.

[How to build a PWA from scratch with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/build-a-pwa-from-scratch-with-html-css-and-javascript/)

PS: You can also explore [web.dev](https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/) to get a thorough understanding.